# overfull \hbox error in \end{align*} line

Tags: align

```
\begin{align*}
[C_{\mu\nu}C^{\mu\nu},Q_{\alpha}] 
&= C_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}[C_{ab},Q_{\alpha}]+[C_{\mu\nu},Q_{\alpha}]C^{\mu\nu} \\
&= C_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}(iP_{b}(\sigma^{ab})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{b}-iP_{a}(\sigma^{ba})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{a})+iP_{\nu}(\sigma^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{\nu}C^{\mu\nu}\\
& -iP_{\mu}(\sigma^{\nu\mu})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{\mu}C^{\mu\nu} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
```

Comment: you have not asked a question! the line is overfull if it is wider than the space where you have put it, and you have given no indication of your text width or font size or anything else that would allow anyone to help

Answer (score 1):

Make the second line shorter by splitting at the `+ iP_{\nu}(\sigma^{\mu\nu})` term.

```
\begin{align*}
[C_{\mu\nu}C^{\mu\nu},Q_{\alpha}] 
&= C_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}[C_{ab},Q_{\alpha}]+[C_{\mu\nu},Q_{\alpha}]C^{\mu\nu} \\
&= C_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}(iP_{b}(\sigma^{ab})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{b}-iP_{a}(\sigma^{ba})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{a}) \\
&\phantom{={}} +iP_{\nu}(\sigma^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{\nu}C^{\mu\nu} - iP_{\mu}(\sigma^{\nu\mu})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{\mu}C^{\mu\nu} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for splitting of second equation line I would use `multlined` environment from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
[C_{\mu\nu}C^{\mu\nu},Q_{\alpha}]
    & = C_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}[C_{ab},Q_{\alpha}]+[C_{\mu\nu},Q_{\alpha}]C^{\mu\nu} \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        C_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}(iP_{b}(\sigma^{ab})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{b}-iP_{a}(\sigma^{ba})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{a})\\ +iP_{\nu}(\sigma^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{\nu}C^{\mu\nu} - iP_{\mu}(\sigma^{\nu\mu})_{\alpha}^{\beta}Q_{\beta}P_{\mu}C^{\mu\nu} 
        \end{multlined}    \\
    & = 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]